# PHP Eclipse - importing existing CakePHP projects

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2, phpeclipse

I'm trying to import existing Cake 1.2 projects into PHP Eclipse (latest all-in-one download on Galileo build) - I don't think I understand Eclipse properly:

1) I have created Workspace on my web root C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs
2) I have created new Project C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\EclipseCake

... how do I import my existing cake project into my new project (EclipseCake) ?

I tried Configure Include Path -> Project -> Add ... but no file browser appears. I'm obviously misunderstanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an "Import" in the menu if you right click the new project's name.What you need to do is click it and choose "Filesystem" and click "next" button.You may read this [tutorial about eclipse](https://eclipse-tutorial.dev.java.net/eclipse-tutorial/part1.html).

Comment: In my version I click Import, then select General, then choose Filesystem. This imports the files into the project. I have also seen that if I right click the new project, choose Build Path and then Link Source, I can link my files into the project without them being copies - ie, remaining in the original directory.